# Наследование конструктора в C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, наследование, конструктор

Я хотел заставить программу наследовать конструктор базового класса для того, чтобы я мог создавать экземпляр наследника.
Я написал следующий код:

```
public class Human
{
    private string Specie = "Homo Sapiens";

    //Создали аксессор, создали поле, создали значение по умолчанию
    public string name { get; set; } = "Иван";

   //Возня с геттерами и сеттерами опущена
        }
    }
}

public class Subject:Human
{

    //А вот эти поля мы скормим в конструктор
    public bool isOldfag { get; set; } = false;
    public bool isCool { get; set; } = false;

    public Subject(bool _isOldfag, bool _isCool) : base(string _name)
    {
        this.isOldfag = _isOldfag;
        this.isCool = _isCool;
        this.name = "test";
    }
```

Компилятор выдал сразу две ошибки:

- **CS1525 Недопустимый термин "string" в выражении**
- **Ошибка CS0103  Имя "_name" не существует в текущем контексте.**

Ума не приложу, где я допустил ошибку. Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Для начала, в `Human` нет конструктора (или вы нам его не показали). Далее `base`, это тоже самое, что вы сделаете `new Human("name")`, то есть вы туда передаете параметры, а не устанавливаете новые. Если у вас `Human` требует через конструктор `string` значение, то в `base` уже должно быть это значение, которое вы задаете сами (прим: `public Subject() : base("Значение")`), либо используете конструктор (`public Subject(string name) : base(name)`).

Comment: [Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) - ознакомьтесь. Глазам больно смотреть.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Human {

    public string Name;

    public Human (string name) {
        Name = name;
        Debug.Log("Human Constructor");
    }
}

public class Subject : Human {

    public bool IsOldfag;
    public bool IsCool;

    // наследуемый обращается к родительскому через base:(string)
    public Subject (bool isOldfag, bool isCool, string name) : base(name) {
        IsOldfag = isOldfag;
        IsCool = isCool;
        Debug.Log("Subject Constructor");
    }

    // сам к себе обращается через this:(bool, bool, string)
    public Subject (bool isOldfag, bool isCool) : this(isOldfag, isCool, "test") {
        Debug.Log("Subject Constructor Short");
    }

    public Subject () : this(true, true, "test") {
        Debug.Log("Subject Constructor No Attrubue");
    }
}
```

---

```
Subject NewSubject = Subject(true, true);
```

Log:

```
Human Constructor
Subject Constructor
Subject Constructor Short
```

[Конструкторы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибки компилятор выдал потому что base(...) -- это вызов конструктора базового класса, а не его определение/объявление, то есть мы как бы говорим: "прежде, чем выполнить мой конструктор, вызови ка конструктор базового класса вот с такими-то параметрами", а следовательно во-первых нам не надо объявлять тип параметра, во-вторых параметр, с которым мы вызываем конструктор базового класса должен быть в области видимости, например, быть одним из параметров конструктора наследника, а конструктор базового должен иметь соответствующую сигнатуру. Чтобы все работало достаточно поправить указанные ошибки: убрать указание типа из вызова, добавить параметр name конструктору класса Subject и добавить конструктор, который принимает строковый параметр name, базовому классу (это, кстати, в принципе, логично, у человека всегда есть имя). Тем не менее в коде есть некоторые проблемы, присущие коду новичка поэтому позволю себе привести свой вариант:

```
public class Human
{
   // Литералы стоит объявлять константами или static readonly, если они публичны
   private const string Specie = "Homo Sapiens";

   // Публичные члены именуются в PascalCase
   public string Name { get; set; } = "Иван";

   public Human(string name)
   {
        Name = name;
   }
}


// Двоеточие в данном случае стоит обрамить пробелами
public class Subject : Human
{
   // bool по умолчанию всегда false, не надо присваивать его явно
   public bool IsOldfag { get; set; }
   public bool IsCool { get; set; }

   // Параметры метода именуются в camelCase
   public Subject(string name, bool isOldfag, bool isCool) : base(name)
   {
       IsOldfag = isOldfag;
       IsCool = isCool;
   }
}
```

Как-то так, если, конечно я понял всё правильно и Вы всё же говорили о цепочке конструкторов. :)